# SOAP for wcf service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

This is my 1st time try with wcf web service.

I created a [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) web service. Testing it with wcf test client, it works fine. But when I copy the xml generated by the wcf test client to postman/fiddler to test the web service, I get error `400 bad request`.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ICompanySVC/GetList</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetList xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>`
```

in postman/fiddler, i use HttpPost on web service hosted in local iis with url localhost:9999/CompanySVC.svc, then use above content in body as text/xml.

web.config:

```
<service name="CompanySVC">
  <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ICompanySVC">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/CompanySVC"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICompanySVC
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Company> GetList();
}
```

Comment: I think its not a proper way to test a WCF contract. The client which you add your service reference makes a request which not contains only **request body**. If you want to test your service out of the your client application you may use https://www.soapui.org/ which has free features to test a soap service. For soapui you can try to test your service over CompanySVC.svc?singleWsdl

Comment: the soap xml is generated by wcf test client

Comment: ok but WCF service needs headers to process request, postman, restclient or fiddler's default headers are not proper for soap request.

Comment: can you give me an example of header needed? the <s:header> is not?

Comment: <s:header> is the soap envelope header not http header. You may look forward about invoking soap endpoint with raw envelope or you may add rest features to your wcf service